# (delete-backward-char) needs an argument?

Tags: debugging, help

I have written a function to yank a selected region n times. I get a warning however because of the `(delete-backward-char)` although it seems to work. Does the `(delete-backward-char)` need an argument?

```
(defun yank-n-times ()
  "yanks the region n times"
  (interactive)
  (let ((n (string-to-number (read-string "Yank n times: "))))
    (dotimes (x n) (yank))
    (delete-backward-char)))
```

**the updated function**

```
(defun yank-n-times ()
  "yanks the region n times"
  (interactive)
  (let ((n (read-number "Yank n times: "))
    (txt (car kill-ring-yank-pointer)))
    (dotimes (x n) (yank))
    (when
    (or (string-suffix-p "\s" txt)
        (string-suffix-p "\n" txt)
        (string-suffix-p "\t" txt))
      (delete-char -1))))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-n y") 'yank-n-times)
```

Comment: I suggest you use `read-number`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes; `delete-backward-char` requires at least one argument.  Press `C-h f` and type "delete-backward-char" to read the docstring.  An excerpt:

> (delete-backward-char N &optional KILLFLAG)
>
> This function is for interactive use only; in Lisp code use
>   ‘delete-char’ instead.

If the function already behaves as you expect, just remove the `delete-backward-char` instruction.  I imagine that might have been intended to remove a trailing newline.  If for some reason you do want the last character of the last yank deleted you could replace the instruction with `(delete-char -1)`.

Comment: I updated my function, if you or any one finds something which could be made more idiomatic i would be gratful to know. My idea with the deletion of the last char was to remove it if it is a space or a new line or a tab from the end of the yankings.